# Java - Why is my variable showing up as 0 In Java?

Tags: java

I'm a new programmer doing an assignment for class. I'm trying to calculate the profit of selling a shoe on different websites. However, when I try to get variable Fee the output comes back as `0`. Please help thanks!

I attempted to make `Fee = 5;` however, the output was still `0.0`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shoe
{
    private double Cost;
    private double SoldPrice;
    private double ShippingCost;
    private double Fee;
    public Shoe()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println( " Enter Cost Of Shoe. " );
        Cost = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println ( " Enter Sold Price Before Fees. ");
        SoldPrice = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println ( " Enter shipping cost. " );
        ShippingCost = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println ( " How did you sell the Shoe? [ Stockx , Ebay , Goat , Local , Grailed , Paypal  ] ? ");
//user MUST enter the provided sites perfectly.
        {
            String choice = input.next();
            if(choice.equals(" Stockx "))
            {
                Fee = 0.09;
//determines what the value of Fee should be set to, depending on where the shoe was sold.
            }
            else if (choice.equals(" Ebay "))
            {
                Fee = (( 0.029) + 0.3 );
            }
            else if(choice.equals(" Goat "))
            {
                Fee = (( 0.095 ) + 5 );
            }
            else if(choice.equals(" Local "))
            {
                Fee = 0;
            }
            else if(choice.equals(" Grailed "))
            {
                Fee = (( 0.065 ) + 0.3 );
            }
            else if(choice.equals(" Paypal "))
            {
                Fee =(( 0.029) + 0.3 );
            }
            else if (choice.equals(" Test "))
            {
                Fee = 5;
//attempted to test if it was just rounding down for variables, however, the output was 0 when Fee was 5.
            }
            System.out.println( +Fee );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Making your code readable, by indenting it properly, would increase the chances of people reading it.

Comment: You know that if you compare your strings to `" Stockx "` those spaces around the word matter, right?

Comment: Hint: try printing out `choice` so you know that the "capture user input" part is working as expected.

Comment: Also, that opening `{` after a `System.out.println` is suspicious.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Scanner.next()` won't return anything starting or ending with a space by default...

Comment: Also: all variable names in java go camelCase. It should be fee, or cost. That makes your code so much harder to read for experienced java coders.

Comment: And note: you could also use equalsIgnoreCase(), and then it doesnt matter if someone types ebay or Ebay.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I'm sorry if I didn't indent properly.

Comment: Since you didn't initialize your fields explicitly the double-fields all get the default value of 0.0. That's where your output comes from, because none of your choices match (because of the leading and trailing spaces).

Comment: You're not checking for null on choice. Not relevant to this question but just another pointer to your code style. Also in java you can now use a switch statement on strings

Comment: Your code shows using double is an overkill. Use float, or even beter use Enum

Comment: else if(choice.equals(" Local ")) is redundant

Comment: It would be easier to read if you followed java coding conventions. Variables and methods start with a lower case letter (fee). Classes start with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Federico klez Culloca is right.

Remove the spaces surrounding the values to test and it will work.

For safety, you can even use the `trim()` method on your input so even if you type `" Ebay "`, it will work.